How can I expand a column of lists into the neighbouring columns (using Polars)?
Say I have the DataFrame:
>>> df = polars.DataFrame({"a": [0, 1, 2], "b": [1, 2, 3], "c": [[1, 2, 3], [2], [5, 0]]})
>>> df
shape: (3, 3)
┌─────┬─────┬───────────┐
│ a   ┆ b   ┆ c         │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---       │
│ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ list[i64] │
╞═════╪═════╪═══════════╡
│ 0   ┆ 1   ┆ [1, 2, 3] │
│ 1   ┆ 2   ┆ [2]       │
│ 2   ┆ 3   ┆ [5, 0]    │
└─────┴─────┴───────────┘

Column c is a column of lists, but I want the lists 'expanded' into the neighboring columns, something like:
>>> df
shape: (3, 5)
┌─────┬─────┬─────┬──────┬──────┐
│ a   ┆ b   ┆ c   ┆ d    ┆ e    │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---  ┆ ---  │
│ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64  ┆ i64  │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╪══════╪══════╡
│ 0   ┆ 1   ┆ 1   ┆ 2    ┆ 3    │
│ 1   ┆ 2   ┆ 2   ┆ null ┆ null │
│ 2   ┆ 3   ┆ 5   ┆ 0    ┆ null │
└─────┴─────┴─────┴──────┴──────┘

How can this be achieved with Polars?
I tried to use polars.explode("c") followed by polars.pivot(), but this creates new columns for each unique value in the lists in column c.
